# Python: Simplest (non-PIL) way to get image metadata (mainly size)

Tags: python

I'm gathering basic metadata for images - mainly their dimensions, although it'd be nice to get any other available metadata as well. The image formats I'm interested in are png, jpg, and gif.

I'm using PIL at the moment, but it occurred to me there may be a simpler way that doesn't involve external dependencies or binary libraries. Is there one?

Comment: A simpler way than using the same library that everyone else uses?

Comment: Glenn, fair point (I'm already using it too), but I thought it can't hurt to ask, sometimes there's hidden goodness out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: No there is not a simpler way than using an external library.

If you are only going to care about one and one file format only, then yes. Then it's easy to implement something specific for that. But if you want to be generic, you need to support a lot of file formats, and then you don't want to do all that work yourself.

To simplify install of PIL, you might look at Pillow, a friendly fork§ that makes PIL easy_installable.

Comment: I think PIL does turn out to be the simplest tool that covers all the cases I care about.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is anything built in, but if you look up those file formats, you will find that the size is encoded near the beginning of the file.

You can use the struct module to parse just enough of the header to work out the size

Answer (score 1):

See [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org), a fantastic library for dealing with bitmap images.  The [`identify`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/identify) tool from the command line suite will do what you want.  There are also a few [Python interfaces](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php#python).